# How to find radius of image view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I currently have an image view that contains a circular image.

I've set it up like so:

```
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

I'm attempting to draw an arc around the circle using UIBezierPath, and I would like to pass the radius of the Image View for the radius parameter.

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: profileImageView.frame.size.width/2, y: profileImageView.frame.size.height/2), radius: IMG_VIEW_RADIUS, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: can't you do using border of image view

Comment: I already set that up, but I'd like to also create an arc that overlaps the border

Comment: Just a hack-why not create an another image view transparent to that and just add its border. Give the second imageview width height decremented by 1 of the first one and add over first image view

Comment: ohhhhh that sounds good. I'm going to try that

Comment: Another way is posted as an answer

Comment: `IMG_VIEW_RADIUS` isn't `profileImageView.frame.size.width/2.`? Also, if you draw in that same image, use `bounds` instead of `frame` for the center calculation, if not (on its superview, use `frame`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Swift 3.0**

Another way

I just added a imageView like this

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Doing the circular bezier path

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.size.width/2,y: imageView.frame.size.height/2), radius: CGFloat((imageView.frame.size.width/2) - 3.5), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

//fill color
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

//stroke color
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

//line width
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0

//finally adding the shapeLayer to imageView's layer
imageView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Now creating an outside border using the same concept

```
let outerCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.size.width/2,y: imageView.frame.size.height/2), radius: CGFloat(imageView.frame.size.width/2 ), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
let outerLayer = CAShapeLayer()
outerLayer.path = outerCirclePath.cgPath

//fill color
outerLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
//stroke color
outerLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
//line width
outerLayer.lineWidth = 15.0
imageView.layer.addSublayer(outerLayer)
```

Now change the `zPosition` of shape layer created for the inner layer as the radius of this is smaller than the outer layer and it should be added at the top in order to be visible

```
shapeLayer.zPosition = 2
```

You need to tweak a bit with the radius of the first inner layer. In my case I just subtracted the radius with 3.5

[image]

Comment: Awesome, do you know by any chance if there's a way for me to add this layer on top of the border?

Comment: @FaisalSyed Ok, I am going to modifu the code with respect to your requirements in 2 minutes

Comment: @FaisalSyed Check now. You have to tweak with the radius values a bit for the inner layer once, and also make sure to change the `zPosition` of the innerLayer added i.e `shapeLayer` in your case else it won't show up

Comment: don't know why was it downvoted earlier, if anyone downvotes kindly comment also whats wrong so that the suggestive improvement can be done

Answer (score 0):

just use border width and border color

```
    profileImageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        profileImageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Comment: I'm trying to add an arc within my border. A border added this way will hide the arc